# How to render properties of objects in React?

Tags: redux

Where exactly should I deal with the problem of this component not loading with the desired `state`?

My render method causes the following error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

...even though the `JSON.stringify` line shows me that the email property does (eventually) exist.

The `console.log` down in `mapStateToProps` confirms that state loads first without the any `user` property (thus causing the error).

Behold my naive attempt to resolve this in my constructor method. It's not working.

What is the right way to deal with this situation? Some conditional inside the render method? Tried that too but still no luck.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class Feature extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            'auth': {
                'user':{
                    email:'',
                    id:''
                }
            }
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchMessage();        // puts the user object into state
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="feature">
                Here is your feature
                {JSON.stringify(this.props.user , null, 2)}
                {this.props.user.email}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log('state',state);
    return { user: state.auth.user }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Feature);
```

/////////// action /////////

```
export function fetchMessage(){

    return function(dispatch){
        axios
            .get(ROOT_URL, {
                headers: {
                    authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_MESSAGE,
                    payload: response.data.user
                })
            })
    }

}
```

///////////////// reducer /////////////

```
var authReducer = (state={}, action) => {
    console.log('action.payload',action.payload);

    switch(action.type){
        case AUTH_USER: return      {...state, error: '', authenticated: true};
        case UNAUTH_USER: return    {...state, error: '', authenticated: false};
        case AUTH_ERROR: return     {...state, error: action.payload};
        case FETCH_MESSAGE: return  {...state, user: {
                                                        email: action.payload.email,
                                                        id: action.payload._id
                                                    }};
        default: return state;
    };
};
```

Comment: It would make it easier to help you if you could add your actions and reducers code.

Comment: done - but my JSON.stringify line tells me that the state is being updated correctly. It's just that split second between component loading, and state being updated that is causing me the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux uses a **global state** called `store` that lives outside your component.

Inside your `constructor` you have a `this.state = {...}` statement. This is a local state that is only available to the `Feature` component.

`connect` from `react-redux` basically connects the info inside the `store` to your component `props` hence called `mapStateToProps`.

Edit your `mapStateToProps` to something like...

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   const { auth: { user = {} } = {}} = state;
   return {
      user
   }
}
```

What it does is try to extract the `user` property from the store and if it doesn't exist yet, set it to empty object. Your error is due to your mapStateToProps accessing the user property that doesn't exist yet. You might want to set a default value as your initialState to avoid this issue.

Comment: OK - your code worked, but that's some intense destructuring that will take me a few minutes to wrap my head around! Your last sentence, setting the initial state, seemed simpler. At which stage would I do that? Back where I use createStoreWithMiddleware?

Comment: Yes, you set the initial state in your create store.

Comment: Not in the first line of my authReducer?

Comment: Cool. Please marked your questions answered if it is indeed.

Answer (score 3):

So here is what is happening.. You are making a server request for a `user` object and on success the received object is stored in your redux store. While performing such an action your component is rendered as follows:

1. You have initiated the request to the server, which means currently there is no `user` in your store and so the component is rendered with `this.props.user` `undefined`.
2. Your request is successful and the `user` object is stored in your store. When this happens `react-redux` will re-render your component with the user object and `this.props.user` is available in your component.

   During the first step since `this.props.user` is unavailable you are getting an error while accessing `this.props.user.email`. Although @jpdelatorre 's answer is pretty good, another thing you can do is simply add a check in your render method.

   ```
    render() {
        let user = this.props.user || {};
        ....
            {user.email}
        ....
    }
   ```

Comment: Happy to help ! :)