# How to render properties of an Array of objects in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, I have the exact same problem as our friend here :

[How to render properties of objects in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733346/how-to-render-properties-of-objects-in-react/40735072)

The below (upvoted) solution by Nahush Farkande :

```
 render() {
     let user = this.props.user || {};
     ....
         {user.email}
     ....
 }
```

works for me... if *user* is an object. However, in my specific case, the data I fetch and want to render is an array of objects.

So, I return something like that :

```
                <ul>                                    
                    {
                        user.map( (el, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <li key = {idx}>
                                    <div className="panel-body clearfix">
                                        {el.title}
                                    </div>
                                </li>               
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
```

That doesn't work. I get an error message that tells me that user.map is not a function (before [HMR] connected).

I expected that once the API fetches the user array of objects, the component would re-render and then the component would show the list of titles from each object of the user array (after [HMR] connected).

Comment: so you want probably something like `(user || []).map(...)` to handle the `null` case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `user` (I recommend to rename to `users`) is an array, then you cannot use `{}` as the default. You should use `[]` as the default value:

```
const user = this.props.user || []
```

or, you can use a completely different branch to handle the loading case:

```
if (!this.props.user) {
    return (
       <div> ... my loading placeholder ... </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Damn!!! I did that before, and I got the same error message. That is why I am posting this new question on SO. 

It actually works now :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You already have correct answer but just wanted to give a running example.

Initialize your data in your state with the default values e.g

in case of `object -> {}`

in case or `array -> []`

Obviously in each case your rendering logic should be different e.g in case of array you need the `map` to loop over array and generate `jsx element`.

So when ever your component receives the updated data ( either it can be empty data or complete data) either via api call or via prop changes use the appropriate life cycle method such as `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentDidMount` to get the latest data and again set the state with latest data.

For example when data is received via api call ->

```
 constructor() {
   this.state = {
      data : []
   }
 }

 componentDidMount()
 {
   this.getFunction();
 }

 getFunction = () => {
     this.ApiCall()
        .then(
            function(data){
              console.log(data);
              // set the state here
              this.setState({data:data});
            },
            function(error){
              console.log(error);
           }
    );
 }
```

So at the time of initial render your data will be either empty object or empty array and you will call appropriate rendering method for that accordingly.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          data : []
     }
   }
 componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ data : this.props.dp });
 }
  renderFromProps() {
    return this.state.data
    .map((dpElem) =>
      <h3>{dpElem.name}</h3>
    );
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
     <h1> Rendering Array data </h1>
      <hr/>
      { this.renderFromProps()}
     </div>
   );
  }
  
}

const dynamicProps = [{ name:"Test1", type:"String", value:"Hi1" },
{ name:"Test2", type:"String", value:"Hi2" },
{ name:"Test3", type:"String", value:"Hi3" }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test dp={dynamicProps} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```